# How to select coordinate position within uv texture in a shader - Unity

Tags: unity, opengl, shaders

first of all I'm sorry for asking noob-ish question. This is my fifth day trying to make a shader in Unity.

I'm trying to select an area within my UV image as shown below

[image: the UV I use]

and here's how it looks like on the mesh

[image: How it looks like in unity]

Basically I'm only selecting the red from the UV and apply it to the mesh. I encountered no problem when trying to select from the RGB, but when i try to use the XYZ for the coordinate position, it turns out that the value of x and r is the same, so is y and g, and z and b.

My question is, how to select by the coordinate position in the UV texture?

Thanks.

here's my code :

```
    Shader "Custom/ASK RGB" {
    Properties {
        _tex ("Tex", 2D) = "white" {}
    }
    SubShader {
        Tags { "RenderType"="Opaque" }
        LOD 200

        CGPROGRAM
        #pragma surface surf Lambert

        sampler2D _tex;

        struct Input {
            float2 uv2_tex : TEXCOORD1;
            float4 pos : TEXCOORD1;
        };

        void surf (Input IN, inout SurfaceOutput o) {
            // my variable used to store the UV texture mentioned
            half4 tex = tex2D (_tex, IN.uv2_tex.xy); 

            // my attempt to use position which doesn't work
            half4 texPos = half4(IN.pos);

            half4 tryUV = tex2D(_tex, IN.uv2_tex.xy);

            tex.a = 1 - tex.b - tex.r - tex.g;

            tryUV.a = tex.r;

            o.Albedo = tryUV.rgb * tryUV.a;
        }
        ENDCG
    } 
    FallBack "Diffuse"
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

.xyz is just the same as .rgb, the idea is that you use whichever makes the most sense in the context you are using it.

I think the values you want are in IN.uv_tex.x and IN.uv_tex.y

Comment: Thanks so much for the fast reply! It works perfectly as I intended! :D